# Install Istio by using istioctl from private registry

Tags: istio

I need to install istio from a private registry, I can set the private registry with "--set hub=xxx.xxx.io" but didn't find a way to provide image pull secrets as my registry is login required.

Comment: What is your istio version? Could you please add a command uou use? Could you try to use `–set values.global.hub=xxx.xxx.io` instead of `--set hub`?

Comment: Hi @Jakub, thanks for your reply, I'm using istio 1.6.5 and install istio by istioctl, I can set my registry with both --set hub=xx or "values.global.hub=xxxx", but I don't know how to provide image pull secret, because my registry is login required

Comment: I think you could follow this [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#configuring-nodes-to-authenticate-to-a-private-registry) to configure your nodes to authenticate to a private registry. Could you try with that?

Comment: I'm using this way now, but I think use imagePullSecrets is still useful and easy to configure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the value you're looking for is `global.imagePullSecrets`.
There is related [github issue](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/4870) and [documentation](https://istio.io/v1.4/docs/reference/config/installation-options/) about that.

```
global.imagePullSecrets []  Lists the secrets you need to use to pull Istio images from a private registry.
```

---

You should be able to change it either with

**istioctl**

```
istioctl install --set values.global.imagePullSecrets
```

---

**or**

---

**istio operator**

```
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: IstioOperator
spec:
  values:
    global:
      imagePullSecrets:
```

---

Additionally [there](https://discuss.istio.io/t/using-pullimagesecret-with-the-sidecar-injector/7907) is thread on discuss.istio about that.