# Istio installation failed with private docker registry

Tags: kubernetes, istio, docker-registry

**Bug description**

Installation gets timeout errors and in `kubectl get pods -n istio-system` shows `ImagePullBackOff`.

`kubectl describe pod istiod-xxx-xxx -n istio-system`

> Failed to pull image "our-registry:5000/pilot:1.10.3": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Head https://our-registry:5000/v2/pilot/manifests/1.10.3: no basic auth credentials

**Affected product area (please put an X in all that apply)**

[x] Installation

**Expected behavior**

Successful installation with `istioctl install --set profile=demo --set hub=our-registry:5000`

**Steps to reproduce the bug**

- Create `istio-system` namespace.
- Set `docker-registry` user credentials for `istio-system` namespace.
- `istioctl manifest generate --set profile=demo --set hub=our-registry:5000 > new-generated-manifest.yaml`
- Verify it has proper images with `our-registry:5000`
- Pull and push required images to `our-registry:5000`
- `istioctl install --set profile=demo --set hub=our-registry:5000`

**Version**

Kubernetes : v1.21

Istio : 1.10.3 / 1.7.3

**How was Istio installed?**

`istioctl install --set profile=demo --set hub=our-registry:5000`

[References]

1. Tried to setup imagePullSecrets as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63721552/install-istio-by-using-istioctl-from-private-registry), but it gives

> Json object error
> 2. [Here](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/27036) describe about using it in charts, but dont know how they applied it.

Originally posted as an [issue](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/34636).

Comment: Just to confirm, you are able to push and pull images to and from your private registry? Which version of Istio are you using? You listed two.
You are using `istioctl install`, but `hub` component is used in installation with operator.

Comment: @p10l Yes, We can pull/push images to our local docker registry.I had tried both separately and both gave the same error. Can you please mention how to install istio with `hub` option. I may have missed something

Comment: I did a bit more research. You can try installing istio with `istioctl install --set values.global.hub="our-registry:5000" --set values.global.imagePullSecrets[0]="<registry-auth-secret>"`. `<registry-auth-secret>` must be created prior on the cluster

Comment: @p10l This is what I tried `istioctl install --set profile=demo --set values.global.hub=our-registry:5000 --set values.global.imagePullSecrets[0]="password"`, still the same

Comment: No, no, not a "password", a [secret](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/). You can read [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/) how to authorize with docker registry using secrets.

Comment: @p10l thanks a lot, it solved the issue, we already created docker-registry password for `istio-system` ns. 
Could you please post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to cirumvent this issue.

#### If installing with `istioctl install`

Using `istioctl install` provide a [secret](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/) with docker-registry auth details with `--set values.global.imagePullSecrets`. Like this

```text
istioctl install [other options] --set values.global.imagePullSecrets[0]=<auth-secret>
```

Where `<auth-secret>` is the secret created prior on the cluster.
You can read more about using secrets with docker repository [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/)

#### If installing using Istio operator

Installing Istio with operator, from private regostry, you have to pass proper YAML:

```yaml
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: IstioOperator
...
spec:
  profile: demo #as an example
  values:
    global:
      imagePullSecrets:
      - <auth-secret>
...
```

Again, `<auth-secret>` must be created prior.